# how to ignore inner lists in scheme?

Tags: list, scheme, racket

I wrote a procedure that gets every value from a list and returns a list where every value is -1(for example)

```
(define (Set-list a val)
  (if ( null? a) (list)
    (append (list val) (Set-list (cdr a) val))
))

(Set-list '(2 3 4) -1) //returns '(-1 -1 -1)
(Set-list '(A(2 3) B(2 3) C(2 3)) -1) // returns '(-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1)
```

how do i make it return -1 -1 -1? I don't want to get the inner members of the list?

Comment: Just to make sure you understand your example: do you think that `A(2 3)` is a single "outer" element with some elements inside? (It's really *two* outer elements, the symbol `A` and the list `(2 3)`. Do you want to *skip* elements that are lists themselves?)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you're confusing how lists work in Scheme. This list: `'(A(2 3) B(2 3) C(2 3))` is *exactly the same* as this list: `'(A (2 3) B (2 3) C (2 3))`. That is, it's a six-element list. If you want to treat the combination of symbol-and-numbers as a single element, pack them together in a single list: `'((A 2 3) (B 2 3) (C 2 3))`

As a side note, the way the `set-list` procedure is written is not idiomatic, in particular using `append` is not the best way to put elements at the head when building a list, use `cons` for that. This is a better way to write the procedure:

```
(define (set-list a val)
  (if (null? a)
      '()
      (cons val
            (set-list (cdr a) val))))
```

Now, following my advice above, here's how it would work:

```
(set-list '((A 2 3) (B 2 3) (C 2 3)) -1)
=> '(-1 -1 -1)
```

**UPDATE:**

Now, if there really isn't a misunderstanding with the way lists work and you just want to replace all sublists in a list with a given value, this will work:

```
(define (set-list a val)
  (build-list (length (filter (negate list?) a))
              (lambda (x) val)))
```

Comment: OP doesn't seem to be confused, see comments. He just wants to skip sublists entirely. (I can try writing it, but it won't be idiomatic scheme, maybe you will?)

Answer (score 1):

Since Anton mentioned about an idiomatic solution, here is my idiomatic solution in Racket (I believe the use of higher-order functions, like `map`, `filter-not`, and arguably `const` is more idiomatic than manually looping and filtering). :-)

```
(define (set-list lst val)
  (map (const val) (filter-not list? lst)))
```

(Racket does provide `filter-map` but it applies the `filter` and `map` in the opposite order from what we want to do.)

Answer (score 0):

Here's my attempt (probably not idiomatic scheme, and please note that doing it with `append` is wrong anyway). I assume that you want to skips sublists entirely, as you explained in comments.

```
(define (Set-list a val)
  (if (null? a)
      (list)     
      (append (if (list? (car a))
                  (list)
                  (list val))
              (Set-list (cdr a) val))))
```

Comment: You are close. If you based your approach on `cons` instead of `append`, your solution would be pretty idiomatic, at least out of the set of solutions that don't use higher-order functions. (See my post for a higher-order-function-based solution.)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make a value's list which length is the same with given lists length,

```
(define (set-list list value)
    (build-list (length list) (lambda (x) value)))
```

so,

```
(set-list '(2 3 4) -1) //returns '(-1 -1 -1)
(set-list '(A (2 3) B (2 3) C (2 3)) -1) // returns '(-1 -1 -1 -1 -1 -1)
(set-list '(2 3 4) -2) //returns '(-2 -2 -2)
(set-list '(A (2 3) B (2 3) C (2 3)) -2) // returns '(-2 -2 -2 -2 -2 -2)
```